# Import components(.tsx) from outside src ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to ReactJs. I need to import an react Component(.tsx) from outside the current project or src. I tried few things like **react-app-rewired** to remove the **ModuleScopePlugin** and I imported the component in my project but when I use the component I get an error..

```
D:/ReactApp/client/src/Temp/Template.tsx 8:2    
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export default function Template(){
|       return(
>               <div><br/>From temp template 1</div>
|       );
| }
```

Template.tsx

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function Template(){
    return(
        <div><br/>from build 1</div>
    );
}
```

Current Project:

- MyApp

  - src

    - page.tsx
  - package.json
  - config-overrides.js
  - tsconfig.json

config-overrides.js :

```
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');

console.log("Override works")

module.exports = function override(config, env) {

    config.resolve.plugins = config.resolve.plugins.filter(plugin => !(plugin instanceof ModuleScopePlugin));
    return config;
};
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
```

Page.tsx

```
import React,{ useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import Template from "D:/ReactApp/client/src/Temp/Template.tsx"
function ViewPage() {
    return (       
        <div>
            Page 1
            <Template />
        </div>
    );
}
export default React.memo(Page)
```

Is this correct? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you need to import more pages from outside better to link that folder as dependency. You can use mono repo using yarn workspaces

Comment: `D:/ReactApp/client/src/Temp/Template.tsx` looks like it's inside the src folder, so what are you trying to do? Create-react-app throws an error if you try to import a file from outside the src folder, it'd become quite a messy project, otherwise. Why don't you make a copy within the src folder?

Comment: @user10384449 `File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js  
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.` does this means convert .tsx to .js and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is converted to ES6 then I could import and use the component. For that I used babel.

```
npx babel ./src/components/ --out-dir dist --extensions ".tsx"
```

package.json

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-react",
        {
          "flow": false,
          "typescript": true
        }
      ],
      [
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        {
          "isTSX": true,
          "allExtensions": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties", "react-auto-binding"]
  }
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0"
  }
```